# React Native - Set localStorage in WebView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, local-storage

I would like to set localStorage in the WebView component before loading the page.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview

My use case for this is that my RN app would like to open a page on it's accompanying website. The website authenticates on load by checking for a token in localStorage. If the token isn't there they will be prompted to login. Seen as the user has already logged in on the app I would prefer it if they could avoid logging in again in the WebView.

Answer (score 4):

You might have overcome the issue. If not here is my solution.

You can use `injectedJavaScript` property of `WebView` and add javascript code to add the token on page load.

Example code snippet.

1. My Custom Javascript code that i need to inject.

```
let myInjectedJs = `(function(){ let tk = window.localStorage.getItem('tokenKey');
      if(!tk || (tk && tk != '${token}')){
        window.localStorage.setItem('tokenKey', '${token}');
        window.location.reload();
      }
    })();`;
```

*Code Explanation*

Function is called as soon as loaded. Checks if **tokenKey** is already set. If not set we are setting it to the new token `${token}` and reloading the page.

Note: We need to pass function as a string to `injectedJavaScript` in webview.

2. Using `myInjectedJs` in WebView.

```
<WebView
    ref={webView => { this.refWeb = webView; }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    injectedJavaScript={myInjectedJs}
    ...
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: this will worked in debug but when i generate release build that not worked.

Comment: Is it possible to do a async and await function to load token first then insert?

Answer (score 2):

[injectedJavaScript](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascript) and [window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#postmessagestr) should do the job.

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT = `(function() {
  const tokenLocalStorage = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(tokenLocalStorage);
})();`;

export default function App() {
  const onMessage = (payload) => {
    console.log('payload', payload);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://somewebsite.com/login' }}
        injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
        onMessage={onMessage}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Payload data:

```
Object {
  "nativeEvent": Object {
    "canGoBack": true,
    "canGoForward": false,
    "data": "your_localstorage_value",
    "loading": false,
    "target": 3,
    "title": "Coil",
    "url": "https://somewebsite.com/home",
  },
}
```

Works on both Android and iOS.