# injectedJavaScript do not work in Webview of react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
const SendLocalStorage = function() {
  if(!window.localStorage.getItem('user')) {
    SendLocalStorage();
  }
  else {
    const data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user')).userId;
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data);
  }
}

SendLocalStorage();
```

I injected recursive function in to react-native web view.
In this code, function wait until local storage has value but this code run only once and never recur itself.
Why this things happen? Can I get local storage value recursively?

Answer (score 1):

Hi it appears to me that you are not injecting the function properly check this link
[React Native - Set localStorage in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078060/react-native-set-localstorage-in-webview)